# MediaWiki: Vector Collapsible Sidebar, first-level headers issue

Tags: vector, header, mediawiki, sidebar

Most of Vector's collapsible sidebar works fine. My issue is that the first-level headers, normally used for navigation, aren't showing up properly. The formatting works as I intended the first time I use it in the sidebar, with the header as a link with no collapsing.

```
* CoreTechs
** Main Page|CoreTechs
```

The second time I use it, I use the exact same formatting and instead it shows up as a collapsible header "Developlement", with a single header, "Home".

```
* Development
** Dev:Home|Home
```

I imagine this is hard-coded somewhere, or that I fundamentally don't understand what I'm doing. I've tried pouring through the MediaWiki page on the subject to no avail.

```
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar
```

Similarly, the Vector extension page wasn't terribly helpful either.

```
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Vector
```

My PHP & CSS skills are zero at the moment, so being pointed in the right direction would be helpful. It seems like it could be a simple enough fix, but it alludes me.

Here is my wiki if that helps:

http://coretechsgame.com/mediawiki-1.19.2/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Sidebar

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
SeeJay

Answer (score 3):

the first level by default always showing like that, i don't know how to hack mediawiki to change that default, but you can tricky by adding * with empty word

like this

```
*
* CoreTechs
** Main Page|CoreTechs

* Collectibles
** Collectibles|Main
```

Comment: Tried, didn't get the desired results unfortunately. I actually want the Nav header "CoreTechs" to show up as non-link text. I guess hacking seems to be the only option. A lot of work for a nav bar :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess.

MediaWiki recognises CoreTech as a link due to the CamelCase. It does not recognise Development as a link since it is not in explicit CamelCase.

Maybe if you're explicit about Development being a link it will work, like so:

```
* Development|Development
** Dev:Home|Home
```

Since they removed collapsible from Vector I don't have a handy wiki to test that on, but it's a theory for you to try.